# Reset the counter if the power key is not pressed for 30 seconds

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an application which would start sending out the message, if the power key is pressed four times.. I have used Broadcast Service and Receiver to make this work.

The problem now is if I click power key two times in the morning and two more times in the evening, still it sends out the message.

I want to restrict the time interval between the power key presses.

This is how my receiver looks like.

```
private static int countPowerOff=0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            screenOff = true;
            countPowerOff++;
            if(countPowerOff==3) {
                countPowerOff = 0;
                SendMessage sms = new SendMessage(context);
                try {
                    sms.sendSMS();
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException ie)
                {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenOff = false;
            countPowerOff++;
            if (countPowerOff == 3) {
                countPowerOff = 0;
                SendMessage sms = new SendMessage(context);
                try {
                    sms.sendSMS();
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a  **CountDownTimer** to reset the counter to 0 after a particular time intervel. Refer [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just store the timestamp everytime you receive

```
private final static int INTERVAL = 30000; //interval you want int ms

private final static List<Long> times = new ArrayList<Long>();

public boolean shouldSendMessage(){
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Iterator<Long> it = times.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Long time = it.next();
        if(time<current-INTERVAL){
            it.remove(); // remove old times.
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    times.add(current); // add current time
    return times.size()==4;
}
```

and replace your `countPowerOff==3` by `shouldSendMessage()`